# String Interpolation inside String Interpolation in C# results in compiler error

Tags: c#, string-interpolation, csc

The following C# expression is resulting in a compiler error in my program:

```
$"Getting image from {location.IsLatitudeLongitude ? $"{location.Latitude} - {location.Longitude}" : location.Location}."
```

Shouldn't it be possible to use String Interpolation like that? Or is it just not possible to do this?

Comment: Using the ternary operator within string interpolation is a bit tricky:
I think you have to add round braces.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160(v=vs.140).aspx), you need to use the following format when using the ternary operator inside string interpolation.

> The structure of an interpolated string is as follows:
>
> ```
> $ "{ <interpolation-expression> <optional-comma-field-width> <optional-colon-format> }"
> ```

Therefore you need to add a set of brackets after { and before the closing } like this:

```
$"Getting image from {(location.IsLatitudeLongitude ? $"{location.Latitude} - {location.Longitude}" : location.Location)}."
```

Answer (score 4):

I just tested this. As i commented, you need braces for a tenery operator:

```
$"Getting image from {(location.IsLatitudeLongitude ? $"{location.Latitude} - {location.Longitude}" : location.Location)}."
```